# Is it always true and how to prove it?

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

If we have a matrix $$\mathbb{A}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbb{B} & \mathbb{a}\\
    \mathbb{a}^T & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$ where $\mathbb{B}=\mathbb{C}+\sigma \mathbb{aa}^T$ is a $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix and $\mathbb{a}$ is a column vector with $n$ elements and $\mathbb{C}$ is also a positive semidefinite matrix. In this case is it always true that $\mathbb{A}$ has exactly one negative eigenvalue? If it is true then how to prove it?

My try:

I know there is theorem (and I do not know how to prove this theorem either and its name either, please provide the name of this theorem) which says that, with the construction of $\mathbb{A}$ provided above, we always have $$\lambda_n(\mathbb{A})\geq \lambda_n(\mathbb{B})\geq 0.$$ But even with this theorem we can say that $n$ eigen values are non-negative but it does not say anything about the $n+1$th eigenvalue. So, I do not know how to use this theorem to prove that $\mathbb{A}$ has exactly one negative eigenvalue. Any help in clarification will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is $\sigma$ strictly positive?

Comment: @LinAlg What if its negative? Does it matter? Actually in my observation its a positive value but I am wondering will it matter if its negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss an important assumption that $a$ is nonzero. The form of $B$ does not matter. Assuming that it’s positive semidefinite is enough.

So you know that there’s at most one negative eigenvalue (thanks to the Cauchy interlacing theorem). The whole matrix $A$ cannot be positive semidefinite since otherwise the zero on the diagonal would imply $a=0$ (zero on the diagonal of a semidefinite matrix implies the whole corresponding row/column is zero). Hence it has at least one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you mean "zero on the diagonal of a positive semidefinite matrix..." or you mean "zero on the diagonal of a semidefinite matrix..."?

Comment: @FrankMoses positive or negative semidefinite, it does not matter for this little statement.

Answer (score 0):

The remaining eigenvalue cannot be positive because if one lets $V$ to be the column vector with zero at every entry except the last entry which equals 1, then $V^TAV=0$.

Comment: and how this answer proves that $\mathbb{A}$ has exactly one negative eigenvalue?

Comment: If all of the eigenvalues of $A$ were nonnegative, then $A$ would be positive semidefinite and $V^TAV=0$ would have meant that $AV=0$ implying $a$ is zero which should be assumed to be nonzero.

Comment: But I think your reasoning is based on the assumption that $\mathbb{A}$ is not positive semidefinite. Why do you assume this?